# Additional JQuery plugins breaking Lavalamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, galleria, lavalamp

I have a site that is currently live, you can visit it at http://www.centennial-s.schools.nsw.edu.au/index.html

It has multiple JQuery plugins including Lavalamp and Galleria. Lavalamp works fine an all pages except for the one that Galleria is also on. If you visit the gallery page of the site you can see that the navigation bar does not have any of the Lavalamp animations on it. So I though that it was  Galleria that was was breaking Lavalamp so I recently tested another JQuery plugin for the gallery, however this also broke Lavalamp. Currently I'm thinking that a variable name that Lavalamp uses may happen to be a common variable name that JQuery gallery plugins also use, but I don't know how to check this as the reason I (and most people) use JQuery is because I don't really understand javascript.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps these plugins reference a different version of Lavalamp to what you are using?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe but I don' think so, both plugins work seperately to eachother. I can get Lavalamp working if I disable Galleria and Galleria works regardless of whether Lavalamp is enabled on the specific page.